# Tensoring with the quotient field of a principal ideal domain

Tags: commutative-algebra, tensor-products, flatness

Let $\mathcal O$ be a principal ideal domain with field of fractions $F$.  Let $A$ be an algebra over $F$, and $A_0$ an $\mathcal O$-subalgebra of $A$.  Since $A_0$ is torsion free over $\mathcal O$, it must be a flat.

- Is the natural $F$-algebra homomorphism $A_0 \otimes_{\mathcal O} F \rightarrow A$ always injective?
- Can we say that $A_0 \otimes_{\mathcal O} A_0 \rightarrow A \otimes_F A$ is injective?

I am rusty at making these kinds of arguments, but I recall that with flat algebras you can generally declare a lot of things to be injections.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes: the homomorphism $A_0\otimes F\to A$ is just obtained by tensoring the inclusion map $A_0\to A$ with $F$ (since $A\otimes F\cong A$), and so it is injective because $F$ is flat over $\mathcal{O}$.  Similarly, the map $A_0 \otimes A_0 \rightarrow A \otimes A$ can be written as the composition $A_0\otimes A_0\to A_0\otimes A\to A\otimes A$ where the first map is the inclusion $A_0\to A$ tensored with $A_0$ and the second map is the inclusion $A_0\to A$ tensored with $A$, both of which are injective since $A_0$ and $A$ are flat.  (Note that $A\otimes_F A$ and $A\otimes_\mathcal{O} A$ are the same thing so you may as well tensor everything over $\mathcal{O}$.)

Comment: From the inclusion $A_0 \rightarrow A$ we get an inclusion $A_0 \otimes_{\mathcal O} F \rightarrow A \otimes_{\mathcal O} F$.  Of course $A \otimes_F F = A$, but do we also have $A \otimes_{\mathcal O} F = A$?

Comment: If $A$ and $B$ are $F$-modules, then $A\otimes_\mathcal{O} B$ and $A\otimes_F B$ are the same: the extra relations on $A\otimes_F B$ imposed by $F$-bilinearity are already implied by $\mathcal{O}$-bilinearity, since elements of $F$ are just fractions of elements of $\mathcal{O}$.

Comment: Or, in the particular case $B=F$, you can use the fact that since $F$ is the localization of $\mathcal{O}$ at all nonzero elements, $A\otimes_\mathcal{O} F$ is the localization of $A$ at all nonzero elements of $\mathcal{O}$.  But since $A$ is an $F$-module, all nonzero elements of $\mathcal{O}$ already act invertibly on it, so this localization doesn't do anything.